# How to configure junit plugin in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I've configured the surefire-maven-plugin in my pom.xml like below:

```
                       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>    
                  <skipTests>${skip.tests}</skipTests>    
                </configuration>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>           
            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>    
        </dependency>
```

Below is my Test class,i am unable to run the test cases i am getting out put as like below
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import io.servicely.ci.*; 

    public class TestJobs {
        @Before
        public void testCreateJobRemote() throws IOException {

            // JenkinsCreateJob jCreateJob=new JenkinsCreateJob(); Boolean b =
            boolean b = JenkinsJob.createJobRemote("http://localhost:8080", "i18n",
                "C:\\config.xml");
            assertEquals(true, b);

        }
        @Test
        public void testUpdateJobRemote() throws IOException {

            Boolean b = JenkinsJob.updateJobRemote("http://localhost:8080", "i18n",
                "C:\\config.xml");
            assertEquals(true, b);

        }
        @Test
        public void testRunJobRemote() throws IOException {

            String response = JenkinsJob.runJobRemote("http://localhost:8080",
                "i18n");
            assertEquals("Created", response);

        }
    }
```

and,i run the command **mvn clean test -e** getting output like below

```
   [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO]
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building Servicely CACDCI POC 1.0
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @servicely-ci-poc ---
   [INFO] Deleting C:\Repo\servicely-ci\POC\target
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ servicely-ci [debug] execute contextualize
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] Copying 3 resources
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @servicely-ci-poc
   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
   [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Repo\servicely-ci\POC\target\classes
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (default) @ servicely-ci-poc
   [INFO] Instrumenting classes with EMMA processing instrumentation path ... instrumentation path processed in 198 ms [8 class(es)
   instrumented, 3 resource(s) copied] metadata merged into
   [C:\Repo\servicely-ci\POC\target\coverage.em] {in 63 ms}
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources
   (default-testResources) @ serv
   [debug] execute contextualize
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] skip non-existing resourceDirectory C:\Repo\servicely-ci\POC\src\test\resou
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
   (default-testCompile) @ servicely [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @servicely-ci-poc --- 
   [INFO] No tests to run. [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Repo\servicely-ci\POC\target\surefire-reports

   -------------------------------------------------------
   T E S T S
   -------------------------------------------------------

   Results :

   Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

   [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 7.852s
   [INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 12 21:54:19 IST
   2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/111M [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I run mvn dependency:tree getting output like below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Servicely CACDCI POC 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ servicely-ci-poc ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.pom (2 KB at 2.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.pom (2 KB at 2.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.pom (3 KB at 5.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/4/maven-shared-components-4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/4/maven-shared-components-4.pom (3 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/4/maven-parent-4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/4/maven-parent-4.pom (10 KB at 19.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.pom (3 KB at 5.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.2/plexus-utils-1.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.2/plexus-utils-1.2.pom (767 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.5/plexus-1.0.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.5/plexus-1.0.5.pom (6 KB at 11.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.1/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.1/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.pom (5 KB at 9.1 KB/sec
)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.pom (360 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-parent/3.0/asm-parent-3.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-parent/3.0/asm-parent-3.0.pom (3 KB at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.pom (4 KB at 7.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/9/maven-shared-components-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/9/maven-shared-components-9.pom (4 KB at 7.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.pom (2 KB at 4.
1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.pom (7 KB at 12.7
 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/7/maven-shared-components-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/7/maven-shared-components-7.pom (3 KB at 5.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0/maven-project-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0/maven-project-2.0.pom (2 KB at 3.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0/maven-profile-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0/maven-profile-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0/maven-model-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0/maven-model-2.0.pom (3 KB at 4.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0/maven-artifact-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0/maven-artifact-2.0.pom (723 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0/maven-core-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0/maven-core-2.0.pom (6 KB at 11.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0/maven-settings-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0/maven-settings-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.pom (2 KB at 3
.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0/maven-reporting-api-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0/maven-reporting-api-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.0/maven-reporting-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.0/maven-reporting-2.0.pom (504 B at 1.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-4/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-4/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-4.pom (2 KB at 2.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.pom (812 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.pom (2 KB at 2.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0/maven-monitor-2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0/maven-monitor-2.0.pom (400 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.pom (2 KB at 2.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.6/plexus-components-1.1.6.pom (2 KB at 3.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.pom (2 KB at 3.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.pom (2 KB at 2.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.pom (141 B at 0.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.4/maven-plugin-api-2.0.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.4/maven-plugin-api-2.0.4.pom (643 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.pom (2 KB at 2.9 KB/
sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.pom (771 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.4/plexus-components-1.1.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.4/plexus-components-1.1.4.pom (3 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.2/plexus-velocity-1.1.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.2/plexus-velocity-1.1.2.pom (8 KB at 14.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom (2 KB at
2.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0.2/plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0.2/plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom (471 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-root/1.0.3/plexus-root-1.0.3.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-root/1.0.3/plexus-root-1.0.3.pom (6 KB at 12.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.pom (740 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.pom (168 B at 0.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.pom (3 KB at 4.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/velocity-dep-1.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/velocity-dep-1.4.pom (2 KB at 3.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.pom (2 KB at 2
.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.6/plexus-utils-1.4.6.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.1/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.jar (33 KB at 33.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.jar (31 KB at 28.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.1/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.jar (27 KB at 22.7 KB/s
ec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar (154 KB at 106.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.jar (42 KB at 53.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar (34 KB at 42.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.jar (32 KB at 63.
6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.jar (27 KB at 3
1.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.6/plexus-utils-1.4.6.jar (200 KB at 93.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar (12 KB at 24.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.jar (14 KB at 23.3 KB/sec)

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.jar (64 KB at 116.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.2/plexus-velocity-1.1.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.jar (13 KB at 25.0 K
B/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.jar (162 KB at 158.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.jar (12 KB at 21.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.2/plexus-velocity-1.1.2.jar (8 KB at 14.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/velocity-dep-1.4.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar (26 KB at 52.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.jar (226 KB at 134.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.jar (38 KB at
76.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.jar (157 KB at 126.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.jar (353 KB at 185.7 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/velocity-dep-1.4.jar (506 KB at 267.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] com.servicely:servicely-ci-poc:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.kohsuke:github-api:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:jar:1.514:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jenkins-ci.main:remoting:jar:2.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.localizer:localizer:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jenkins-ci:trilead-ssh2:jar:build214-jenkins-1:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.0:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.219s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 12 22:38:23 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my complete **pom.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <description>Cloudly CACDCI Solution</description>
    <groupId>com.servicely</groupId>
    <artifactId>servicely-ci-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Servicely CACDCI POC</name>
    <url>http://www.servicely.io</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8 </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <ciManagement>
        <system>jenkins</system>
        <url>http://54.209.75.142:8080/</url>
    </ciManagement>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://www.github.com/Horoppa/servicely-ci</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://www.github.com/Horoppa/servicely-ci</developerConnection>
        <tag>dev</tag>
        <url>scm:git:https://www.github.com/Horoppa/servicely-ci</url>
    </scm>
    <mailingLists>
        <mailingList>
            <name>team.all@horoppa.com</name>
        </mailingList>
    </mailingLists>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>github</system>
        <url>http://www.github.com/Horoppa/servicely-ci/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jenkins-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
            <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.514</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Comment: Paste the whole class along with the imported packages. And for goodness sake, use the code formatting in the WYSIWIG editor.

Comment: Also, run Maven like this `mvn clean test -e` and paste the output.

Comment: i pasted the output please find it

Comment: Like I said, when posting code and output, please make sure you are using the code escaping button, as nobody would really care to help you. People on Stackoverflow will generally be helpful, but not if you just spew some unformatted output out there. Please,  take some time and learn how to use the editor.

Please, paste the output of one more thing: `mvn dependency:tree`. Also put `<scope>test</scope>` inside youre JUnit `<dependency/>`'s definition.

Comment: i run mvn dependency:tree i pasted the output please find it and i tried with <scope>test</scope>.Even though unable to run test class

Comment: i can't run the test cases what was the folder structure i have to follow

Comment: Could you perhaps also post your complete `pom.xml`? Also, why are you using such an old version of junit? Could you try with the one I showed you?

Comment: i used vesion 4.11 which is suggested by you even though i am getting same results like    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0   i pasted my complete pom.xml please find it

Comment: yes,its working i gave wrong folder structure

Comment: If my answer is correct, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 17):

You need to have JUnit as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version> <!-- Or whatever JUnit you're using. -->
</dependency>
```

And you should actually be running:

```
mvn clean test
```

**EDIT:**

You problem is this:

```
   <configuration>    
       <skipTests>${skip.tests}</skipTests>    
   </configuration>
```

This tells the `maven-surefire-plugin` to (obviously) skip the tests. Just remove that line.

Comment: i already added dependency even though i am getting error message

Comment: Do you have the proper import?

Comment: i am able to run but my test report is                             Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 my test class not executing

Comment: i just pasted my test class

Comment: @user3292916 When you added your test class you removed many details that was there in your original question. This edit makes it harder for us to follow all the steps. Please put them back in if you can.

Comment: Sorry for that,Now i pasted my previous code and Test class i am unable to run my test class getting build falure report as         Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: I specifically asked you to paste the entire class along with the imports. If you have no imports, well, then the error is normal -- you have not statically imported `assertEquals`. If, on the other hand, you have imported it, then providing more code and info on your code and environment, could help us figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: i added with imports also please find it

Comment: Updated my answer with the fix.

Answer (score 2):

first You need to add dependancy

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then you need to add the test directory along with the source directory in the build tag

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
          <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
```

Important - make sure your test class name is like - *Test*.java.

If there is no Test in your test class file name - then maven will not be able to find your Test classes.

the you also need to add the goal in your plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now - if you run Maven install or Maven Test - it will execute all your Junit tests

If you want maven report for all Junit - you can use Surfire plugin in build

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sureFireVersion}</version>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: "Important - make sure your test class name is like - Test.java." yes, this one in really important! I faced with this typo...

Answer (score 1):

Adding this block to your pom.xml will be enough. This code block is inside of project don't add inside of build.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```